# Magento 2- code-migration installation using git

Tags: git, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have got the [link](https://github.com/magento/code-migration) for the tool to migrate code of Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x.

I have tried following command in cmd to install this module -

```
composer config repositories.code-migration git https://github.com/magento/code-migration

composer require magento/migration:dev-master
```

I am getting below exception -

```
` Problem 1`
    - The requested package magento/code-migration-develop could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

`Potential causes`:
 1. A typo in the package name
 2. The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: hi, how is your progress?

Answer (score -1):

change

```
composer require magento/migration:dev-master
```

to

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.2
```

quoting reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html#install-github

> composer require magento/data-migration-tool:< version >
>
> where < version > must match the version of the Magento 2 codebase.